# Migrate Sharepoint 2016 custom Application page to Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration

I have a SharePoint 2016 on-premise environment with custom application page and connected with sql database. Our company has recently purchased O365/SharePoint Online.

How do I proceed these application pages to SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom server side code cannot be deployed to SharePoint Online. You can however build your own client side customisations e.g. web parts for SharePoint Online using SPFx.